# finding astrology signs according to your month and date, simpler way to do it? instead of 12 if function

Tags: python, if-statement

```
if month == 12:
    if 0 < date < 23:
        return 'SAG'
    if 23 <= date < 32:
        return 'CAP'
if month == 1:
    if 0 < date < 21:
        return 'CAP'
    if 21 <= date < 32:
        return 'AQU'
if month == 2:
    if 0 < date < 20:
        return 'AQU'
    if 20 <= date < 30:
        return 'PIS'
if month == 3:
    if 0 < date < 21:
            return 'PIS'
    if 21 <= date < 32:
            return 'ARI'
```

I am looking for a simpler and more effective way of completing my function of finding astrological sign according to month and date, is there a more effective method or is using 12 if loops a must?

Comment: Another pattern you could try is making a list of date boundaries and defining a function to compare two dates. That way you can iterate over the list and return the correct value once the input date matches.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to think there's a better way.  Use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) package.  Set up a list of start dates and check the appropriate range for the given date.  Since Capricorn spans the calendar year, you'll have two entries for that one:

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

signs = [ # start date, abbreviation
    (date(month=1, day=1), "CAP"),
    (date(month=1, day=20), "AQU"),
    (date(month=2, day=18), "PIC"),
    ...
    (date(month=12, day=19), "CAP"),
    (date(month=12, day=31), "end of year"),
]
```

Now, you build a `date` from the given month and year.  Iterate through the list, looking for the a given date being greater than the current date, and less than the next one.  When you find that entry, you report/return the sign abbreviation.

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are always tough to work with and mapping the lunar calendar to the solar calendar present special problems. It becomes easier if you approach it from a days in the year problem instead of a dates problem.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt 

def getSign(birthDate):
    #get day of year of birth
    dayOfBirth = (birthDate - dt(birthDate.year, 1, 1)).days

        #adjust for leap years
    if birthDate.year%4==0 and dayOfBirth > 60:
        dayOfBirth -= 1

    #build dict of max day for each sign. capricorn  is set twice due to straddling of solar year
    signs = {20:'Capricorn', 49:'Aquarius', 79:'Pisces', 109:'Aries', 140:'Taurus', 171:'Genini', 203:'Cancer', 234:'Leo', 265:'Virgo', 295:'Libra', 325:'Scorpio', 355:'Sagitarius', 365:'Capricorn'}

    #create numpy array of maximum days
    daysArray = np.array(list(signs.keys()))

    #get sign max days closest to but larger than dayOfBirth
    maxDayCount = min(daysArray[daysArray >= dayOfBirth])

    return signs[maxDayCount]



>>> getSign(dt(2000, 3, 22))
'Aries'
>>> getSign(dt(2000, 1, 1))
'Capricorn'
>>> getSign(dt(2000, 12, 22))
'Sagitarius'
>>> getSign(dt(2000, 12, 31))
'Capricorn'
```